# database engine for windows mobile

Tags: database, windows-mobile-6

I have to make an app for a device running windows mobile 6. I need a small, easy to use database engine or even a flat file database. It won't need to hold a big amount of data. I just want to be able to add/view stored data quickly. The app will be written in c/c++ or maybe .net.

What do you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Compact 3.5 database...you can download it on 
[link text](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx)

.Net 2008 has Smart Device Development for Mobile Applications.

Goodluck!